# UICollectionViewController and UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am new in Swift. I have 3 `UIViewControllers`:

1. `MainScreenController`
2. `RegistrationFormController`
3. `LoginFormController`

and 1 `UITabBarController`

1. `MainTabBarController`

and 2 `ColletionViewControllers`:

1. `VideoController`
2. `TopVideoController`

When I click on the button on the `LoginFormController` to open `MainTabBarController` with either 2 `ColletionViewControllers` seems an error, the error is mentioned below:

> 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'

AppDelegate:

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {
   override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
      return .lightContent
    }
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var navigationController: UINavigationController?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    if let window = window {
        let mainVC = MainScreenController()
        navigationController = CustomNavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)
        window.rootViewController = navigationController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.darkBlue
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

Help me to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618053-init), you need to use `init(frame: CGRect, 
collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout)` when initializing your collection view controllers.